# Replacing elements in long list Python

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to replace a number of elements (around 40k) from a much larger list (3 million elements) with a tag. The code below works however it is extremely slow.

```py
def UNKWords(words):
    words = Counter(words)
    wordsToBeReplaced = []
    for key, value in words.items():
        if(value == 1):
            wordsToBeReplaced.append(key)
    return wordsToBeReplaced

wordsToBeReplaced = UNKWords(trainingWords)

replacedWordsList = ["<UNK>" if word in wordsToBeReplaced else word for word in trainingWords]
```

Is there a more efficient way of replacing elements in such a large list?

Comment: Try making `wordsToBeReplaced` a set instead of a list.

Comment: What you are trying to do is replace words in `trainingWords` whose count is **1** right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `wordsToBeReplaced` a set instead so that lookups can be done in constant time on average rather than linear time:

```
def UNKWords(words):
    return {word for word, count in Counter(words).items() if count == 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can squeeze out a little more performance by avoiding the Counter and just keeping track of the words you've seen more than once. This effectively removes a loop from your function and lets you collect the words you've seen more than once in a single loop:

```
def UNKWords(words):
    seen = set()
    kept = set()
    for word in words:
        if word in seen:
            kept.add(word)
        else:
            seen.add(word)
    return kept

def replaceWords(words):   
    wordsToKeep = UNKWords(trainingWords)
    return ["<UNK>" if word not in wordsToKeep else word for word in trainingWords]
```

…and then use sets instead of lists to test for membership, as others have mentioned, since these allow constant time membership tests.

Comment: @Ch3steR, try that with `trainigWords = ['hello', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'hello']`

Comment: Yes, I understood now what I'm doing wrong. Great solution. +1.

Comment: The `collections.Counter` module is more efficient than you think. Please see demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ForthrightRustyScale

Comment: @blhsing I don't think that test is very representative of the problem — the lists in the problem are much bigger (and also you never called `UNKWords2` in your repl). Here's one with a much larger list that actually calls both functions: https://repl.it/repls/EsteemedCurlyMetrics This result is closer to what I am getting locally too.

Comment: @blhsing, I should add, however, that I agree in general that `Counter()` is generally very quick and can win as the ratio of dupes/non-dupes changes.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Oops indeed my bad for not calling `UNKWords2` in my demo code. Avoiding unnecessary count additions is indeed faster after all. +1

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @blhsing's answer I suggest using a frozenset; also doing the replacement in-place (unless, of course, you need to keep the original list for other purposes):

```
def UNKWords(words):
    return frozenset(word for word, count in Counter(words).items() if count == 1)

wordsToBeReplaced = UNKWords(trainingWords)
for i, word in enumerate(trainingWords):
    if word in wordsToBeReplaced:
        trainingWords[i] = '<UNK>'
```

Comment: No reason to use a frozenset when there is no need to for it to be hashable here.